# My Bitcoin Transaction is Unconfirmed from last 10 days Please Help

Tags: mining-pools

Tx id

> 9c9fb0d1c60f6f59196c9c41c1b9eb7ad9caf32397f5264f54149af6ecfd8003

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Use RBF (Replace By Fee) to increase your fees and expedite your confirmation time.

Comment: I am new to crypto, can you guide how to use RBF

Comment: It depends on the wallet software you use.